# Remove transitional dependency on Scala library

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

One of the libaries in my project is adding a dependency on `scala-continuations`. As this is only used for features of the library I am not using, I want to remove the dependency. This can be done by using:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.jsuereth" %% "scala-arm" % "1.4" exclude(
  "org.scala-lang.plugins", "scala-continuations-library_2.11"
)
```

This works, however I do not like the `_2.11` part.  I could use

```
 excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization="org.scala-lang.plugins"))
```

currently no other artifacts exist with this organization name, however it smells to me, as this can change in the future.

I can compose the name from `scalaVersion` by using string operations:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.jsuereth" %% "scala-arm" % "1.4" exclude(
  "org.scala-lang.plugins", "scala-continuations-library_" + scalaVersion.value.split('.').dropRight(1).mkString(".")
)
```

Is there perhaps some shorter way to do this - some SBT function or perhaps wildcard operation for exclude, or at least to determine the Scala version suffix needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBT contains a predefined key `scalaBinaryVersion`, which can be used like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.jsuereth" %% "scala-arm" % "1.4" exclude(
  "org.scala-lang.plugins", "scala-continuations-library_" + scalaBinaryVersion.value
)
```